# Analytic function in some region containing the closed unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I need help with the problem 6 of the chapter VI section 2 from the book "Functions of One Complex Variable" by John B. Conway.

The problem ask for find a formula for a supposed function $f$ that is analytic in some region that contains the closed unit disk such that $|f(z)| = 1$ for $|z| = 1$.

Assuming that $f$ have no zeros in the open disk I can see that $f$ has to be some constant of module one in the closed disk (Applying Maximum Modulus Theorem to $f$ and $1/f$).

But I don't know how to extend that to all the region or what I can do when the function have zeros in the open disk.

Comment: "I don't know how to extend that to all the region."  It's constant on the entire complex plane.  Do you mean something else?

Comment: $f(z)=z^n$ is an example with a $0$ in the disk, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: @saulspatz thank you, I was able to see that is constant on the entire complex plane. My problem is that I can't complete that cases when $f$ have zeros, I have that examples but I don't know how to continue to give all the posibles formulas for $f$.

Comment: So the problem is "Find all functions $f$ analytic on a region including the closed unit disk, such that $|f(z)|=1$ when $|z|=1$."  Is that right?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, that is exactly the problem.

Comment: look up finite Blaschke products